# Documents needed for travel to neighboring country while passport is already endorsed for entry with valid Schegen Visa

Tags: passports, austria, liechtenstein

Is it mandatory for one to carry the original passport all the time while cross Liechtenstein to Austria for a day break and also carry the Driving licence and IDP?

Comment: To be safe and not interrogated for long carry those documents, if stopped by any authorities. You might not need it ever, but who knows. Anyway doesn't the Schengen visa ask you to carry the documents with you always.

Comment: @DumbCoder From images I have seen of the Schengen Visa, it say nothing of the kind.

Comment: Note that there are three different IDP's (issued under the 1968, 1949, and 1926 conventions).  Austria recognizes the 1968 IDP; I don't know which Lichtenstein recognizes (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/driving-in-the-eu-after-brexit-international-driving-permits#check-which-type-of-idp-you-need just says "a UK licence is all you need").  Be sure you have the right sort!

Comment: Oh joy!  Lichtenstein needs a 1926 IDP - see https://www.simonweir.co.uk/post/international-driving-permits, so if you need an IDP in Lichtenstein and Austria, you will need two different ones.

Comment: @MartinBonner Correction: That blog site **claims** (without source) that Liechtenstein needs a 1926 IDP from foreigners. The Liechtenstein government pages states only that it **issues** 1926 IDP. What it requires from Foreigners is **not** stated. Switzerland requires it only when the  vehicle categories are **not** written in latin letters. https://www.ch.ch/en/international-driving-licence/

Comment: Thank you all for the details.I had asked this question to understand how serious it was to not have the passport as well as IDP with Driving licence. Appreciate your help and info. We did drive from Liechtenstein to Austria basically to go to Feldkirch which was barely 21 kms but one has to cross border control. We ask the police in Liechtenstein is passports are need to cross as we didnt have it & they said it was okay to pass without it and as we drive few yards from this side to Austria border control-they stop us and fined 400, let off after paying 200 and to return back with passport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are crossing a Schengen border, you must *de jure* be in possession of a valid passport or accepted national ID card.

In many countries (I believe Austria to be one) you need to be able to identify yourself (passport or EU member state national ID card) if the police asks you to.

If you are driving, of course you must have a valid licence on you at all times.

---

*De facto* it is very likely for nothing to happen and nobody to ask. So you could get away with it if you want to test your luck. I’m not recommending it because the consequences can be a severe nuisance.

Comment: By "EU ID card", I take it you mean "national ID card issued by an EU member state"?  It sounds like an ID card issued by the EU - which doesn't AFAIK exist.

Comment: @MartinBonner Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Most European countries require, **upon demand**, that you identify yourself and in cases of foreigners their legal status.

For this your passport and visa is required.

A driver's licence is for driving and is not considered an identification of nationality and legal status.

Comment: You might want to add something to the last paragraph like "If you are going to drive a vehicle, you will need to carry with you the document(s) that prove your right to do so.  This will certainly include your driving license. If your license is one which is only recognized in conjunction with the appropriate IDP, you will need one of those too."

Comment: @MartinBonner As apposed to Passports, to get a Driver's license you need a test that proves you know the rules about driving. So explanations about how to use a driver's licence (other than it can't be used as a passport) is off topic in a travel forum.

Comment: A question like "As a citizen of India, I want to take a day trip from Lichtenstein to Austria; what documents do I need to take with me?" would be on topic here, and the answer should including "Driving license, and up to two IDPs".  It is not too much of stretch to imagine that is exactly what the OP's question should have been. (I don't know if an Indian citizen requires an IDP in Austria or Lichtenstein - but given the OP mentioned one, I am guessing he needs at least one.)

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, but a holder of a driver's licence who asks if, while driving, needs a driver's licence **should not drive**. As to IDP: if the answerer does not know the answer about the IDP portion, then that portion of the question should not be answered. Better no answer than an incorrect (or unsourced claim from a blog). Inprecise questions should get answers where the portion that is clear is understood.